# Do neutral particles interact with EM radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, dipole

This question has been bugging me for a while. I asked my professor, I read a couple of posts here and from other sources and some people say that neutral particles interact with light and some people say they don't.

My question is: if we had any free neutral particle and if a photon comes towards and hits this particle, what would happen? Will they collide, scatter, transfer any energy? Or nothing would happen?

Comment: Do they have a magnetic moment like neutrons?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Let us say yes and no. I mean we can consider the two case seperatly. That would be more general and nice answer for me

Comment: If nothing else, they could interact gravitationally (or, in particle-physics language, scatter via graviton exchange.)  But I suspect this you want to confine things to the Standard Model as currently understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Particles at the level [of elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) interact with photons either directly, as with electron photon scattering, or through intermediary virtual loops into charged paritcles, which is necessary in the case of neutrinos.  Even [photon+photon scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics) has to go through an intermediary level,:

[image: photphot]

From the left two photons come in and on the right two photons go out, having interactd through a loop of [virtual](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html)  charged elementary particles from the table linked above.

Comment: +1, A more mundane case is the fact that the neutron interacts with electromagnetic fields due to its magnetic moment. The interaction of the neutron with the electric fields of atoms is a major actor in neutron spectroscopy, but I am unaware of a context where interaction with EM *radiation* is relevant though...

Comment: So even itds neutral it has an interaction somehow. I see